# typeahead.js : How to remove value when value not in suggestion

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I use `typeahead.js` as autocomplete textbox.

At first, when I input and select a value from the suggestions, textbox sets the value correctly. Then, I input a value that is not in the suggestions and press tab and the value of the textbox doesn't clear.

How do I clear the value of the textbox when the input value is not in the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same situation and the way I solved this was by using the events of `typeahead.js`. I record a selection on `typeahead:select` and then check on `typeahead:change` if the selection was made. If no selection was made, I reset the input to the original value.

```
// Initialize typeahead as ususal
var $myTypeahead = $("#my-typeahead");
$myTypeahead.typeahead(/* Set-up typeahead here */);

// Set up variables to store the selection and the original 
// value.
var selected      = null;
var originalVal   = null;

// When the typeahead becomes active reset these values.
$myTypeahead.on("typeahead:active", function(aEvent) {
   selected       = null;
   originalVal    = $myTypeahead.typeahead("val");
})

// When a suggestion gets selected save that
$myTypeahead.on("typeahead:select", function(aEvent, aSuggestion) {
   selected = aSuggestion;
});

// Once user leaves the component and a change was registered
// check whether or not something was selected. If not reset to
// the original value.
$myTypeahead.on("typeahead:change", function(aEvent, aSuggestion) {
   if (!selected) {
      $myTypeahead.typeahead("val", originalVal);
   }

   // Do something with the selected value here as needed...
});
```

Comment: Can you please share Codepen demo?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `typeahead.js` with [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), which I highly recommend due to it's power, there is an option called `freeInput` that you can turn false to not allow tags that are not returned by typeahead's source.

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  },
  freeInput: false
});
```

That way, your tags will be limited to what the source returns, like Amsterdam, Washington, Sydney ...

Answer (score 0):

now in 2020 I have the same issue, i share with yours my code, solve my problem.

Afert typeahead input i have a hidden input to capture id of selected element.

Typeahead have event called " render: Fired when suggestions are rendered for a dataset. The event handler will be invoked with 4 arguments: the jQuery event object, the suggestions that were rendered, a flag indicating whether the suggestions were fetched asynchronously, and the name of the dataset the rendering occurred in. "

Use this event and checking value of hidden input i wrote this code:

#pais is typeahead input.

#id_pais is hidden input.

```
$('#pais').bind("typeahead:render", function(e, data, name) {
  $('#id_pais').val('');
});

$('#pais').bind("typeahead:change", function(e, data, name) {
  var valor = $('#id_pais').val();
  if (valor == '' ) {
    $('#pais').val('');
  }
});
```

sorry for my english, im spanish speaker.

Answer (score -1):

Just check for the tab key code when keys are pressed...

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'typeahead_name',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: typeahead_name.ttAdapter()
    }).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if( e.which == 9 ) {
            console.log('tab pressed!');
            $('.typeahead').val(''); // clear typeahead field
            return false; // prevent further action
        }
    });
```

List of keys you can use:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
More info on jQuery Keydown event: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: I don't think this would work. It'll clear the input even if a valid suggestion was selected. Additionally, it doesn't take into account all the other ways that a user could `blur` out of an input with an invalid selection (e.g. just clicking out of the box).